# Using "Transact-SQL" instead of LINQ in a PLUG-IN to retrive and write data to CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Just wondering ho to use ﻿﻿"Transact-SQL" instead of LINQ in a PLUG-IN to retrive and write data to CRM.

Is it the same as when we use ﻿"Transact-SQL" in a C# application to retreive and write data to an sql server?

I would appreciate it if you provide some example helpful links.

Thank you in advance.

Nawaf﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transact-SQL updates/insert are not supported.  Transact-SQL reads are only supported when accessing the views.  Use the SDK to retrieve / update CRM.